# Elements combination of same array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

In my project, i will have to receive a string from user (in textarea). Now this `string` will be converted into `array`. Now the problem is that, the character length must be minimum of 3, 
in the following array next element should be joined to current one if character length is less than 3. How to perform it in `PHP`.

```
a[0]=>this a[1]=>is a[2]=>an a[3]=>example a[4]=>array.
```

Output should be:

```
a[0]=>this a[1]=>isan a[2]=>example a[3]=>array.
```

Comment: How does `[1]=>is a[2]=>an a` give `[1]=>isan a`, and why should those elements be merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$input  = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'array.'];
$output = [];

$part = '';
foreach ($input as $value) {
    $part .= $value;
    if (strlen($part) > 3) {
        $output[] = $part;
        $part = '';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'this' (length=4)
  1 => string 'isan' (length=4)
  2 => string 'example' (length=7)
  3 => string 'array.' (length=6)
```

Comment: Thanks hsz for the solution, needed.

Comment: @ImranKhanMicro Remember to accept an answer with the tick on the left.